# Sign form submition(PDF) with a digital signature

Tags: web-services, digital-signature, digital-certificate, client-certificates

## TL;DR

- Have online form
- On submission PDF is generated
- Problem: How to digitally sign the PDF with the client certificate from within the browser?

## Background

In EU and US (and my country) there is law that makes digital signatures (preformed with client certificates issued by government and government approved CAs) legally binding.

Currently I have a webform - equivalent to a paper one - where users submit their personal information. I use that data to generate a PDF that they download, print out, sign and mail to us by mail. Non-optimal to say the least.

Most of my target users already have these client certificates (online banking and taxes) so I'm hoping to enable users with these certificates to sign the PDF thus making it legally biding and saving them a trip to the post office.

## Problem

How do I sign a PDF with the client certificate, taking into account this has to be done with the private key and that the client only sends the public key to the server.
Obviously this has to be done on the client side, but not Javascript as it does not have access to certificates (Java, Flash, ActiveX do).
I've found a bunch of proprietary solutions for this but non that are free software / open source.

The webapp is written in PHP(Symfony2) and Javascript, runing on a Ubuntu server with nginx and php-fpm.

Any suggestions on how to approach this without reinventing the wheel? Does anyone know of a free/open library/applet that would do this?

---

Some links:

[Digitally sign a PDF on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626639/digitally-sign-a-pdf-on-the-server)
(2011, asp.net, one answer explains basic flow)

[Web application to sign PDF documents with digital certificates released by CAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955410/web-application-to-sign-pdf-documents-with-digital-certificates-released-by-cas)
(2011, similar question)

Comment: If you also are interested in how that can be done in Java (both client and server side), you may want to have a look at [Digital Signatures for PDF documents](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures), a white paper for iText. Section 4.3.3 "Signing a document on the server using a signature created on the client" seems to be your use case. Concerning *free/open library/applet* --- iText is available either AGPL licensed or commercially. You would have to decide whether the AGPL conditions are ok for your context.